# Jacobian criterion algebraic independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have two polynomials $f_{1}(x,y)$ and $f_{2}(x,y)$ and I want to know if they are algebraically independent.

I am using the Jacobian criterion which says that $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are algebraically independent if the determinant of the Jacobian is non zero.

So far I have worked out the Jacobian $$J = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}$$

And my determinant is a polynomial of $x$ and $y$. My question is how do I show that this is non zero? Is it enough that none of the terms cancel each other and so therefore is non zero?

Comment: Yes, a polynomial $h(x,y)$ is zero if all terms cancel each other.

Comment: Thanks, so because I still have $x$ and $y$ terms, it is non zero? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Yes. What are your algebraically independent polynomials ?